# Will lender title insurance need to be bought again if refinance with same issuer?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, refinance, title-insurance

If I refinance my mortgage with same lender, will I need to pay for new lender title insurance ?

I understand, I can ask the lender, but before I do I want to know how is the experience of other stack-flow readers?

Comment: @yoozer8 that question is for owner's title insurance, this question is for Lender's Title insurance

Comment: The answer specifically says *"you are required to purchase a new lender's policy of title insurance"*. Does that not answer this question?